# add custom legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with `ggplot2` to generate some `geom_line` plots which i've already generated from another `data.frame` which is not important to mention here. but it also contains the same `id` value as the following dataframe.

I have this data frame called df:

```
id    X   Y     total
1   3214 6786   10000
2   4530 5470   10000
3   2567 7433   10000
4   1267 8733   10000
5   2456 7544   10000
6   6532 6532   10000
7   5642 4358   10000
```

What i want to do is create `custom legend` which present for a specific id the percentage of `X` and `Y` on each of the `geom_line` for when the `id` variable is the same. So basically for each `geom_line` of e.g(`id=1`, draw the percentage for that `id` in the `geom_line` plot)

I've tried to use `geom_text`, but the problem is that it's printing everything in one line which i cannot see anything of it.

how this can be done ??

***EDIT***

`olddf` dataframe is something like that:

```
id pos X Y Z
1
1.....
1
2
3
4
3 ......
.
.
```

that's the code that i've tried

```
for(i in df$id)
{
test = subset(olddf, id==i)
mdata <- melt(test, id=c("pos","id"))
pl = ggplot() + geom_line(data=mdata, aes(x=pos, y=value, color=variable)) + geom_text(data=df, aes(x=6000, y=0.1, label=(X*total)/100), size=5)
}
```

[image]

Comment: you should post the code you have so far with the problem you face with geom_text and paste the figure that results from your code to make your post much more informative.

Comment: (+1) for the nice update. However, in addition, could you provide the data for `olddf`? I'd like to provide you with an answer, but I need the data to work with.

Comment: @Arun thank you, the olddf dataframe is so big to be presented here ... but basically `id, pos, X, Y and Z `have values similar to the ones in df, so you can just create a random `df` with similar values.

Comment: Two questions: 1) What's the range of `X,Y,Z`, because your plot shows values between 0 and 1 while the `df` has values in thousands. 2) `Z` is not shown in `df`. Why is it necessary in `olddf`?

Comment: @Arun `X,Y` are from `1 to 5000` but what's plotted is (e.g for `X` : `X/Z)`. `Z` is the same as total in `df`

Comment: Okay good. hold on. :)

Comment: Okay, again, you want the percentage ox `X` and `Y` on each of the points of both `geom_line`? This is not quite clear...

Comment: basically, in each geom_line i want to present this geom_text that i've showed .. which is the percentag of X and Y based on the id ...

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to explain better than that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23977/discussion-between-ifreak-and-arun)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (as discussed in chat) is quite straightforward:

Change `geom_text(data = df, ...)` to `geom_text(data = df[df$id == i, ], ...)`